# Share variable in nginx locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Is it possible to share a variable among location directives?
e.g)

```
location / {
    set $myvar "XXX";
.
.
.
}
```

and then access $myvar in location /app1

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_set_header $X-MY-HEADER $myvar; #currently this line not working
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you want to achieve? Exactly this code does not make any sense, unless you have any `rewrite ... last;` rules only one location would be used for any particular URI processing.

Comment: i am using oauth2-proxy with nginx to authenticate users with oauth/oidc tokens. oauth2-proxy doesnt implement access control.So I can successfully authenticate and get access token in location / (using $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token). But I want location /app1 to be only accessible to roles which are included in the token. Basically I want to access the $accesstokenvariable in location /app1 where I have implemented my own auth_request code to allow/deny access

Comment: people can login to the home page at "/" but further access to e.g) app at location/app1 needs to be controlled

Comment: Why don't put this token into a cookie? I don't see any other way to achieve it except keeping the token in a cookie or within the basic auth header.

Comment: how would go around doing that?I am not a webdeveloper so if you could point me to an example that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your access token into a cookie so the user browser would send it with the each subsequent request:

```
location / {
    ...
    add_header Set-Cookie "access-token=$upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token; Path=/app1";
}
```

Then you can check the `access-tokes` cookie value from your webapp or set your custom HTTP header from that cookie value from nginx config:

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_set_header X-My-Header $cookie_access_token;
    ...
}
```

Note that the `access-token` cookie in this example is specified without the `Max-Age` value, so it would persists only until the end user closes his browser. If you want, you can also specify the cookie expiration time, for example 24 hours:

```
add_header Set-Cookie "access-token=$upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token; Path=/app1; Max-Age=86400";
```